# Why isn't Windows recognizing 7GB of my graphics card's VRAM?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, nvidia-geforce

I've just swapped out a 4GB GeForce 960 for an 8GB GeForce 1070, and I'm noticing some inconsistent behaviour between Windows's `System Information` screen and Nvidia's control panel.

While the Nvidia control panel correctly recognizes it as having 8192MB of available VRAM (under `Dedicated video memory`), Windows stubbornly insists that only ~1MB is available (1,048,576 bytes).

Whenever I launch a task that hits the VRAM a lot -- for example, rendering scenes with high-resolution textures -- it becomes really clear that I've got far less than 8GB available, and even less than my original 4GB, since texture loading gets aborted long before it's complete, usually after only a tiny part of the textures are loaded. I'm not sure that this reflects one *megabyte* of VRAM being available, but it still renders many games unplayable.

I've updated the video drivers through Windows, and am running version 385.69.

What could cause this kind of discrepancy, and how can I get my system to correctly recognize the amount of VRAM this card has available?

I'm on Windows 10.0.15063.

Comment: Those are the same version. Look at the last 5 digits of the Windows version.

Comment: `385.69`.isn't the current version of the Nvidia drivers.  385 isn't even close to the current version by the way, you are looking at, almost 3 month old drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't say it's the current version; I said it's the version Windows pulled down (at best, the latest version according to Windows). GeForce Experience is unfortunately out to lunch for some reason (the window loads up without content or interactivity), so I'm also limited in automatic driver management -- but I'm fetching newer drivers manually.

Comment: You said you updated the drivers typically that means the current version

Comment: Fair enough, sorry about the misunderstanding, then; Windows has a different definition of "current" than most of us.

Comment: Windows is giving you three week old drivers from early Sept when the 1709 build went gold